# jQuery post inside Promise - multiple posts to backend, possibly blocking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, promise

I have a function `DoThings` which gets invoked by `onInput()` of inputs in table rows. The rows can be updated at any time.

My problem is that if I update row `#1` and `#2`, `DoThings()` gets invoked but the first `$.post` seems to hold up the second `$.post` until it returns. I can confirm this with breakpoints in my server code. The second request hit the server only once the first request has returned to the client.

Now, I'm really not sure what's happening here. Any ideas how I could fix this to allow concurrent `$.post`s in this situation?

I may also be misusing Promises.

```
function DoThings() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         validate = $.post(uri)
            .done(function (data) {
                //some stuff happens            
                resolve('success');
            })
            .fail(function (data) {
                reject('failure');
            });
    });
}

//Usage
DoThings().then((data) => {
    //other things
});
```

EDIT: The server is running ASP.NET 4.5. In dev tools I can see that both requests are sent nigh simultaneously but the second one clearly waits for other to return.

Comment: Strange behaviour. For  sequential requests, you would normally need to write the code very deliberately. I have to suspect that your analysis of what's going on is flawed in some way - sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, I am also very suspicious of this (I understand that there's no reason anything should be blocking here). And I'm struggling to pin down the problem. There must be some misuse happening here.

Comment: `DoThings()` will simplify to `function DoThings() {
    return $.post(uri) .then(function (data) {
            // some stuff happens            
        });
}`. Depending on how it's used, it's possible that the non-localised `validate` variable is somehow messing you up.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, thanks for insight. I'm looking at that `validate` possibly being the issue

Comment: After removing all non-local members from the `DoThings()`, the requests still seem to be sequential.

Comment: Mmm, it was a good idea while it lasted :(

Comment: It's got to be some feature of the server-side set-up.

Comment: So this seems to a problem on the back-end. The server is locking down the user session for read/writes and blocks incoming requests (only for the same user) until it is done processing the first request. I don't feel I know enough to provide an answer to this yet.